# Replace url(../fonts/*) with url(../fonts/fontawesome/*) with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, gruntjs, font-awesome

I want to replace this url-attribute:

```
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.WhichEverEnding')
```

with the following:

```
url('../fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.WhichEverEnding')
```

My question now is, how would the RegEx for this in JS look like?

Here is what I tried unsuccessful (it's part of a grunt-task):

```
module.exports = {
  fontawesome: {
    src: ['assets/dev/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css'],
    overwrite: true,
    replacements: [{
        from: 'url(../fonts/',
        to: 'url(../fonts/fontawesome'
    }]
  }
}
```

I am not surprised, that this did not work, however I am fairly new to Grunt and RegEx for that matter, so I am grateful for any hint!

Comment: Did you consider defining `fontawesome` as a symlink to its parent directory?

Comment: Hey, thanks for that hint. Unfortunately this definition comes from a plugin, so I can't touch it.

Comment: I'm not suggesting touching the plugin. I'm suggesting adding a symlink to your project's directory structure so you **don't** have to touch the plug-in or fool around with obtuse grunt rules.

Comment: I understood that wrong. Sorry. However I decided to go another way and just copy the files and delete the folder later on. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

A simple javascript replace should do what you want:

```
 '../fonts/test2123.svg'.replace(/\.\.\/fonts\//g, '../fonts/fontawesome/')
```

output:

```
 "../fonts/fontawesome/test2123.svg"
```